# JQuery .each and iterating with raw Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, audio

I am trying to accomplish something like this

```
var audios = $('audio');

for(var i = 0; i< audios.length;i++){
    if(audios[i].currenTime != 0)
        audios[i].pause();
}
```

But when I use JQuery to do it it returns to me that it doesn't have any method.

```
$('audio').each(function(){
    if($(this).curentTime !=  0){
     $(this).pause();
    }
});
```

Is there anything I am missing?

Comment: jQuery object != DOM element. Don't use `$(this)`, but `this`.

Comment: Argh! I forgot about that one!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When using `.each()` the callback receives the DOM element as `this`. You can (and have to) use it directly instead of wrapping it with jQuery again.

```
$('audio').each(function() {
    if(this.currentTime != 0) {
        this.pause();
    }
});
```

- When you want to access the element, use `this`
- When you want to call jQuery functions on the element, use `$(this)`
- Never use `$(this)[0]`, that's like `['Hello'][0]` instead of `'Hello'`

Comment: That clearly made sense!  but why shouldn't I use $(this)[0] ?

Comment: See the last line of my answer.

Answer (score 2):

`$(this)` is a jQuery object , you need to get the dom element with `$(this)[0]` or `$(this).get(0)`, but you should not do that, just use `this` directly.

```
$('audio').each(function(){
    if(this.curentTime !=  0){
     this.pause();
    }
});
```

Comment: `$(this)[0]`? Why would you do that?

Comment: `var a = ['hello'][0];` seems legit

Comment: Yep, that's true, `$(this)[0]` is non sense.

Comment: @FlorianMargaine: yes, it's legit in the same sense as `parseInt((1).toFixed(0))` is a legit way to get `1` - it gets the job done but is a pointless complication :)

Answer (score -1):

you cant check for $(this).currentTime, as $(this) is a jquery object,

```
$('audio').each(function(){
    if($(this)[0].curentTime !=  0){
     $(this)[0].pause();
    }
});
```